# How to crop text between braces

Tags: mysql, sql, string, text, trim

I have data in MySQL in one string field with below structure:

```
{language *lang_code*}text{language}{language *lang_code*}text{language}
```

And here is example:

```
{language en}text in english{language}{language de}text in german{language}
```

The ideal output for this would be in this case

```
text in english
```

So we want to disregard the other languages, just want to extract the first one, and put it into new column, because it's often the title of the product, with translations, and for us the first one is the most important.

The values in first braces may be different, so for example here the first one is english, but in other example it might be in german, so the *lang code* might also be dynamic.

I am wondering if it's possible to extract the text value between two first braces through SQL query?

Comment: This is really a fundamental design flaw of storing multiple atomic values in a single column; if you had the text stored in a separate column, 1 row per each value, and a separate column for the language, you would have no issues.

Comment: What are you expecting as an output? Two rows? One row with both text values concatenated? One row with two columns? One row with N columns? N rows? Please add more detail.

Comment: hi Stu! you are 100% right - I am also aware of that, but that is the issue we have with our client database, that is not managed by my team.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback - I have added more details to the question.

Comment: Presumably you've investigated the available [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) already, what have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: yes, sure I have investigated those functions, but out of the box none of them seems to be correspondent to that issue. main issue that I see is the fact that the position of the text may vary based on the *lang code* is being used. the best query that would come to my mind is the query that takes data after first } and finishes at second {, but I don't know how to achieve that in SQL. that's where the question comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really horrible but it works for your simple example -

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REGEXP_SUBSTR('{language en}text in english{language}{language de}text in german{language}', '\\{language en\\}(.*?)\\{language\\}'), '}', -2), '{', 1);
```

or

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REGEXP_SUBSTR('{language en}text in english{language}{language de}text in german{language}', '\\{language de\\}(.*?)\\{language\\}'), '}', -2), '{', 1);
```

to retrieve the german text.

To retrieve the first text in the string regardless of language you can use -

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REGEXP_SUBSTR('{language en}text in english{language}{language de}text in german{language}', '\\{language [a-z]{2}\\}(.*?)\\{language\\}'), '}', -2), '{', 1);
```

Note this version assumes the language code is always 2 x a-z chars - `[a-z]{2}`

Here is an example of the above wrapped in a stored function -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `ExtractLangString`(content TEXT, lang CHAR(8))
RETURNS text
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    -- if lang is not 2 chars in length or lang not found return first language string
    IF LENGTH(lang) <> 2 OR content NOT LIKE CONCAT('%{language ', lang, '}%') THEN
        SET lang = '[a-z]{2}';
    END IF;
    RETURN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REGEXP_SUBSTR(content, CONCAT('\\{language ', lang, '\\}(.*?)\\{language\\}')), '}', -2), '{', 1);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

There is probably a cleaner way of doing it but I cannot think of it right now.

Obviously, the better solution would be to normalise the data that is currently serialised into this column.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer!

I have one more challenge to that - do you think it would be possible to take always the first text in the string, because we always try to obtain the first text, but it sometimes can be in English/German/Japanese, and I think with fixed looking it may be difficult.

Comment: So you want to extract the first text regardless of language? Always?